# trigger to populate manager's manager in a lookup field

Tags: trigger, lookup

Way too new at coding to be able to figure this out, hoping someone has done this and can help me out or get me started.

Need to use the managers' manager on an approval process for a custom object so need to set this as a lookup field I can reference.

Comment: How many approval level's are there ?

Comment: Three levels. Manager - Manager's manager and a named user representing the Regional VP.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case you have to write triggers in both the objects (User and Custom Object).

In custom object, the trigger should fire whenever the record is created or the owner of the record is changed. And then you can query the Manager's Manager and assign it to the lookup (User) field.

In User object, the trigger should fire whenever the Manger of the user is changed. Then update the lookup (User) field by the new manager.

You can use this Lookup (User) field in Approval process.